# Is it worth synchronizing I/O intensive threads in order to increase total disk performance?

Tags: .net, windows, multithreading, performance, io

Our Windows .NET application has several I/O intensive threads that are writing to the disk (rotational media) constantly. A write operation from one thread is done without it being aware of the other thread's write operations, so this means that the write requests hits the Windows I/O manager in the same order that the calls happens to be performed.

There has been a discussion in our project if this is the right way to do it or if we could gain some performance by synchronizing the write operations so that only one (or a few) thread(s) ever perform a write operation to the disk at the same time (maybe by a shared lock). The theory is that this would put less strain on the CPU and also give us better throughput (please note that we are already using asynchronous I/O for all our operations).

I'm a bit skeptical to this whole idea, since I think we would then be doing part of the job that the operating system originally was designed to solve. Have now performed some experimentation and it points in the direction that there are no benefits at all. It is my impression that, as long as the buffer sizes are sufficient, the decision when to write blocks to the disk is better left to the operating system to decide.

So could someone please enlight us? Is it a good idea to synchronize disks access from a multithreaded process in order to gain performance? Are there any differences in this regard between e.g Windows or Linux?

Comment: How big are the files you're writing? How big is the data in total?

Comment: In this use case we constantly write to the disk and when the files reaches a certain size we close them and start a new, so maybe 50 MB each. And the total is maybe 75% of the available disk. It all depends on the retention time.

Comment: This is not so important for writes, because the OS can delay and elevator-sort them.  Reads and flushes cause real performance problems, if unrelated ones are issued simultaneously, because the disk ends up spending more time seeking than actually doing I/O.

Comment: Of course, all these problems become insignificant with solid-state drives which don't require seeking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The theory is that this would put less strain on the CPU

How could it? It's the same number of writes but now with added synchronization. It will create (a little) more CPU load.

> we would then be doing part of the job that the operating system originally was designed to solve.

Sadly, Windows is not capable of performing any kind of intelligent IO scheduling. I'm unsure what the disk driver does. With NCQ and SATA there certainly is some degree of reordering of operations. But I have never observed Windows do something intelligent regarding IO (except prefetching which works well).

The main question is whether you want to perform sequential or random IO.

1. Sequential: Multiple sequential streams result in Windows breaking up the streams into 64KB or 256KB chunks making them highly random. This is truly awful. In this case you can gain orders of magnitude performance by intelligently issuing large IOs.
2. Random: Issue many IOs at once so that the disk hardware can reorder them. SQL Server for example sometimes issues thousands (and totally blocks out other processes during that time - be aware of that. Windows has no practically working notion of IO fairness.)

I don't know much about Linux but at least it *has* some kind of IO scheduling. The Windows team does not seem to want to address this.

Comment: On SSDs this shouldn't matter much, but on HDDs I often notice that two concurrent sequential IO operations slow each other down a lot due to lots of unnecessary seeking between them. But since these usually were file copies, and thus a mix of reading and writing, I'm not sure to which degree this is true for pure writing, which can be buffered.

Comment: @CodesInChaos try it. Copy from one volume to the next and look at the physical IOs using procmon with advanced output. It is not pretty. Often, NTFS will even allocate clusters perfectly interleaved leading to maximal fragmentation. So in addition to inefficient IO scheduling we also get maximal fragmentation at the NTFS layer. Hard to find any positive aspect here.

Comment: Also, this does matter on SSDs as well since random SSD IO is 10x slower than sequential. For magnetics disks it's 100x.

Comment: Am I reading this correctly if I walk away with the impression that the best thing to do is to do as much processing as possible and then write it all out at the end, instead of writing everything out as I go?

Comment: @jpmc26 the best thing to do is to see to it that IO is sequential. For uncached IO: You can write data in a trickling way, no problem, as long as the individual IOs are big enough to warrant the disk seek. Cached IO: You can trickle-write without a problem. Writes go to the Windows cache first and are flushed in big sequential writes in the background.